# Defining custom general delimited input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Ruby allows [general delimited input](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/The_Ruby_Language_General_Delimited_Input.html) as follows:

```
%q/this is a string/
```

This is only defined for a few characters as the prefix like %r for regular expressions and %x for shell commands. Is it possible to define custom general delimited inputs in Ruby?

Comment: That's part of Ruby's parser which cannot be altered from within Ruby.

Comment: BTW, what kind of input do you want to parse? There's probably another solution to your problem

Comment: @Stefan: Just interested in possibility, don't have a specific use case in mind

Comment: Btw. they're called percent strings/literals and there's also `%W` (unquoted version), `%s` (symbol) and the new-ish `%i`/`%I` (array of symbols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s not possible to do so in Ruby. You would have to modify the Ruby interpreter itself.